# How double equal == syntax work in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

How does the following code work?

```py
result = session.query(Customers).filter(Customers.id == 2)
```

Based on my non-solid Python knowledge, the `Customers.id == 2` is either not a valid syntax use in a function call? Or such a `foo == bar` syntax will be eval to a boolean first, and then call `.filter(True/False)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Re your statement:

> Or such a `foo == bar` syntax will be eval to a boolean first

You can *override* the equality operator by using the `__eq__` dunder method (and other operators with equally suitably-named methods).

---

For example, the following code shows how to confuse anyone that uses the class, unless they're quantum physicists well versed in the fact that things can be both dead and alive at the same time:

```
class Confusing(object):
    def __eq__(self, other): return True
    def __ne__(self, other): return True

deadCat = Confusing()
liveCat = Confusing()
if (deadCat == liveCat and deadCat != liveCat):
    print("Superposition of meow and deathly silence")
```

---

In your case, `Customers.id` is a `Column` type. I haven't looked at the specific SqlAlchemy code, but `Column.__eq__()` is almost *certainly* going to be returning some filtering object, rather than a simple `True/False` value, which will then be passed to the `filter()` method of the thing returned from `query()`.

Here's a greatly simplified variant of that concept, when you have a key/value collection that you can add to, and the result of an equality check is a list of all the keys that have the requested value:

```
class KeyValCollection(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._keyVals = []

    def add(self, key, val):
        self._keyVals += [(key, val)]

    def __eq__(self, compVal):
        return [item[0] for item in self._keyVals if item[1] == compVal]

x = KeyValCollection()
x.add("pax", 42)
x.add("arthur", 43)
x.add("bill", 42)
x.add("carl", 44)
x.add("david", 42)

print(x == 42)
```

As expected, the output of that is neither `True` nor `False`:

```
['pax', 'bill', 'david']
```